# How to check if the given function/surface has multiple local max or min?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, optimization, differential-topology, convex-optimization

Consider the following function of $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ that each lie in $\mathbb{R}^1$:
$$\frac{-10x_1+10x_2-x_3}{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$$

How do I check if this function has multiple local max or min? It's clear that when $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$, then the function is not defined. Fixing two of the $x_{-i}$ equal to 0 and letting $x_i$ approach 0 makes the function unbounded. Depending on the direction we approach from, the function will either go to positive infinity or negative infinity. What I am interested in knowing is that does this function have any local minimum or maximum? Further, what about the more general case where we have $x_i$ and $i=1,\dots,N$ and the number we multiply each $x_i$ with in the numerator is given/fixed and known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

Calling $X = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $\vec v = (a,b,c)$ we have

$$
f(X) = \frac{X\cdot \vec v}{||X||^2}
$$

so the relative minima/maxima follow the condition $X = \lambda \vec v$ or

$$
f(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\lambda}
$$

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry. I am having some difficulty understanding this. What is relative minima/maxima and how does the condition $X=\lambda \vec{v}$ follow? How does this differ from the typical local minima and maxima where the partials equal 0? And what is $\lambda$? Is this any real number? If that is case, does this suggest that the only maxima and minima are positive and negative infinity? Depending on the direction from which I move $\lambda$ closer to 0?

Comment: Attached a plot showing for the two-dimensional case the $f$ surface as well as the line of potential maxima/minima $({a\lambda,b\lambda,\frac{1}{\lambda}})$ in blue. No local minima/maxima are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, let's rename $(x_1,x_2,x_3) \to (x,y,z)$ and consider the resulting function $$f(x,y,z) = \frac{10y-10x-z}{x^2+y^2+z^2},$$ looking for its local optima.

The candidates for local optima will be given by the equation $\vec{\nabla} f = \vec{0}$, which results in 3 equations:
$$
0 = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
  = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
  = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}.
$$
Can you compute the partial derivatives and finish solving the system?

Comment: I computed the partial derivatives. These are three quadratic equations (once we remove the denominator due to the zero on the other side of the equation). I don't know how to solve these three quadratics simultaneously. The general form for derivative with respect to $x_j$ is $$\frac{-x_j^2 y_j - 2 x_j (\sum_{-j}x_i y_i) - (\sum_{-j}x_i^2)y_j{(\sum x_i^2)^2}$$ . Where $y_j$ is the number multiplying $x_j$ in the numerator. Clearly, this becomes 0 for each partial if all $x_i=0$. How do I solve this system for other solutions? Is there an easy way to show that other solutions exist?

Comment: $$\frac{-x_j^2 y_j - 2 x_j (\sum_{-j}x_i y_i) - (\sum_{-j}x_i^2)y_j}{(\sum x_i^2)^2}$$ Made a typo above and it won't let me edit. This is the derivative with respect to each $x_j$.

Comment: @user52932 the numerator doesn't look right to me -- all variables have different coefficients in the numerator. What are the $y_j$?

Comment: The $y_j$ are the numbers that multiply the $x_j$ in the numerator of the original expression. So $y_1$ is -10, $y_2$ is 10 and $y_3$ is -1. The numerator is a quadratic in the variable we take the partial with respect to. So to clarify, derivative with respect to $x_1$ is as follows:$$\frac{10x_1^2 - 2x_1 (10x_2 - x_3) +10 (x_2^2+x_3^2)}{(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)^2}$$

Comment: I would plug into Mathematica or Wolfram Alpha, or use a numerical solver.

Comment: I tried doing that and for multiple starting guesses, it defaults to all $x_i=0$. That is clearly the obvious solution as it would make the numerator equal 0. But then we are also dividing by 0 and so the problem is undefined. I was wondering if there is some other way to prove whether another local optima exists.

Comment: Or does the fact that the optimizers are defaulting to $x_i=0$ suggest that there are no other local optima?

Comment: @user52932 not sure. i am not convinced there are no other optima

Comment: Do you know of any other tricks other than the partial derivative equal to 0 to characterize an optima? Do you know what people do in general if the system is non-linear and hard to solve?

Comment: @user52932 there are no other tricks, but sometimes you can use an optimizer instead of a solver, it would stumble on other solutions.

Comment: How would I use an optimizer? So in this case, I have 3 partial derivatives i.e. the gradient vector is 3x1. Will I take a dot product of the gradient vector with itself and minimize that quantity? Thanks for you help so far btw.

Comment: @user52932 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent for example, see the examples there